# How to use nodemon as a develeper dependency

Tags: npm, nodemon

I am trying to use nodemon as a developer dependency on my project but for some reason it is not working. I installed in successfully via:

```
npm install -D nodemon
```

But when I run it I get an error that says "command not found".

To answer Lahori's question, I am running in via CLI like this:

```
nodemon script.js
```

Comment: how r u executing it? like this nodemon script.js?

Comment: Yes, this is how I am running it.

Comment: did u install it globally? with the -g flag i.e. npm i nodemon -g ?